# VBA Using a userform data to copy from a workbook into a new workbook

Tags: excel, copy-paste

My code is suppose to take input from the user, via userforms, then based on that input go from sheet to sheet and copy specific rows, and paste them into a new workbook. I have been trying all these different ways to create a new workbook, copy and paste, but I haven't had any success. I have gotten error 9, and tried to find a way to fix that. But with all my efforts I have yet to find a solution. I am very new to VBA and could really use some help, even if its just basic explanation of certain ways to copy and paste.

Comment: Show an example of your file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You really need to share what you've tried in order to get any meaningful help. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30844732/edit) your post to include the code you have along with an indication of the line that is generating an error.